# Local is 5 commits ahead of remote origin master, how can I see what will be uploaded?

Tags: git

I had accidentally added a large 20mb file to git, and I did an -ammend and removed the file.

Before doing a git push origin master, I want to make sure the file was removed.

I tried doing a git push origin master, and it was taking a long time and the transfer reached like 7mb so I figured the large file is still in the history somewhere.

How can I figure out if the large file is in git's repo history?

Comment: No, it just says 'your branch is ahead of 'origin/master' by 5 commits.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to purge a huge file from commits history in Git?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2100907/how-to-purge-a-huge-file-from-commits-history-in-git)

Answer (score 8):

You could see a diff with:

```
git diff origin/master
```

Or you could get the information by each commit with:

```
git whatchanged -p -5
```

The -p outputs the diff and the -5 means show the last 5 commits, since you are 5 ahead. Alternatively

```
git whatchanged -5
```

does the same thing, but instead of showing the diff, shows the files that are changed and the before and after hashes for the file.

Answer (score 3):

You can use

```
$ git log origin/master..
```

to see the commit messages for everything in your current branch (probably `master`) that's not in `origin/master`.

Comment: ... and the OP should probably add `--stat` so they can see if the file was added or deleted in any of those commits.

Comment: Ok in 2 seperate local commits, I have this very large file (one at the root and one in a folder).  How can I delete these permanently so that other developers won't have to download 50mb of files!

Comment: @Blankman: You probably want to ask that in a separate question.